# New Google Plus Navigation?

Tags: android

Any ideas on how the new navigation in Google Plus is coded (where you hit the "< HOME" button and it pops out a list of activities ("Stream", "Profile", "Messenger", etc)).

I initially have been thinking it is a PopupWindow...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to:

[image]

http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html

then there is nothing built into Android that provides a complete implementation of this at this time. [This blog post](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html) discusses that UI pattern and points to some preliminary open source implementations.

Comment: This has been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FrameLayout` with `layout_width~=200dp` and any height, toggle the visibility of the `FrameLayout` and any other items on the action bar(like tabs, icons etc.,) when the `<Home` button is clicked.